# How to create a JSON object in Geocortex to be used in Crystal Reports

Tags: json, geocortex

Does anybody know if it's possible to convert a dataset containing unique ID's in Geocortex workflow to a JSON object so that it could be used in Crystal Reports?  My knowledge of Geocortex is quite limited so hoping someone may know the answer.